# What should I check if Kovri can't connect to peers?

Tags: kovri

I downloaded a recent (pre-)alpha build on my RPi3 (Raspbian Lite - Jessie 8.0) using `wget`.  It installed fine and runs.  The problem is it never actually connects to peers.

I get only warnings and errors.  After hours and hours, it's still the same messages.

Are there some tests I can try to ensure there is nothing wrong with my system?  Are there system processes that are taken for granted to be running correctly that perhaps I can look into?

(Note that I've run the Java I2P router from another computer on this network, so I would think it's not router/firewall related.)

Comment: "The problem is it never actually connects to peers" : how do you know that ?  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to open an issue on Kovri's GitHub repository. Stack Exchange isn't the best location to do back-and-forth troubleshooting.

https://github.com/monero-project/kovri/issues